# git rebase or merge a certain commit to be beween two other commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a master branch, with commits:

```
a->b->c->d->e
```

At a certain point I checked out a branch called `fix` from commit `c`

```
c->f->g
```

So the big picture is like this:

```
a->b->c->d->e
     \
      \->f->g
```

I would like to perform the merge so that in the linear tree `f` and `g` are between `c` and `d`:

```
a->b->c->f->g->d->e
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rebase the e branch onto the g branch:

```
$ git checkout e
$ git rebase g
```